# Looping through the button always give me 0 answer

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here's the code:

```js
/*this code works fine in code snippet and (when I run the code in the chrome console but when I write the code in my file.js, this won't work*/
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
alert(btn.length);
// it must alert 3, but I always get 0. Please help me. Thank you
```

```html
<button>Games</button>
<button>Foods</button>
<button>Movies</button>
```

Comment: I am seeing 3 in alert

Comment: Actually, if you press "Run code snippets", it does alert 3, which is the desired behavior

Comment: When I clicked "Run code snippets" i seeing 3 in alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the js after document ready .use with `window.onload` function

```js
window.onload=function(){
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
alert(btn.length);
}
```

```html
<button>Games</button>
<button>Foods</button>
<button>Movies</button>
```